Phase of a biproper transfer function
I would like to prove the following:
Let $H(s) = \frac{s^n + b_{n-1}s^{n-1} + \ldots + b_0}{s^n + a_{n-1}s^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0}$ be a stable, minimum-phase and biproper transfer function (i.e. no poles or zeros in the closed right half plane) with the monic numerator and denominator polynomials (leading coefficients of both are 1) with $b_0 > a_0$. Then there is an $\omega \ge 0$ such that $\angle H(i\omega) < 0$, i.e. there is a frequency at which the phase is negative.
Some experimentation in MATLAB like below suggests that this is likely true.
n = 4;
% create two random monic Hurwitz polynomials
ss1 = rss(n); % random stable state space system
p1 = charpoly(ss1.A); % characteristic polynomial of Hurwitz matrix
p1 = p1/p1(1); % normalize to make it monic
ss2 = rss(n); 
p2 = charpoly(ss2.A);
p2 = p2/p2(1);
if (p1(end) > p2(end)) % make b0 > a0
    b = p1;
    a = p2;
else
    b = p2;
    a = p1;
end
% create transfer function and plot magnitude and phase
bode(tf(b,a))

Is the above statement true? If so, how can it be proved? Perhaps Bode's gain-phase formula might be useful?

Do you mean for all $\omega$ or for all $\omega\ge0$?

Good point, I did mean $\omega \ge 0$. I will edit the question accordingly.

My intuition says yes, but I have not been able to prove it. I also stumbled onto the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{arg}!(H(i,e^{x})),dx$$ for which it seems to hold that this integral is only a function of the ratio $b_0/a_0$ and is negative when $b_0>a_0$.

@Kwin van de keen. Interesting, could you please point me to a reference on that integral?

@Siva I don't have a reference for that integral unfortunately, it just seemed to be the most logical integral to evaluate when looking at the phase of Bode plots with frequencies on logarithmic scale.

@Kwin van der Veen A couple of follow ups: 1. What is the reason song that this integral only depends on $b_0/a_0$? 2. With the substitution $\omega = e^x$, that integral would be $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\omega} \arg H(i\omega)\text{d}\omega$, and if it can be proven to be $< 0 $ for $b_0>a_0$, that would prove my statement as well.

@Siva that integral would indeed be equivalent to my previously mentioned integral. And for the reason that it only depends on $b_0/a_0$ is not known to me yet, it was just an observation, which is why I thought that this integral was worth mentioning. If it indeed can be proven that that integral is negative for $b_0>a_0$ then it would also imply that there has to be at least some frequency range at which the phase is negative.

Kwin van der Veen's integral indeed computes to be negative, again doing an experiment in Mathematica like this: matvars = Import["coeff.mat"]; (Import 
random coefficients from MATLAB)
a = matvars[[1, 1]];
b = matvars[[2, 1]];
h = (b . s^Range[Length[b] - 1, 0, -1])/(a .
s^Range[Length[a] - 1, 0, -1]);(Create the transfer function)
NIntegrate[
Arg[h /. s -> I [Omega]]/[Omega], {[Omega], 0,
Infinity} (Do Kwin van der Keen's integral) But don't know how to prove it. Maybe something along the lines of the proof of the argument principle?

The key to the following proof is the integral suggested by Kwin van der Veen above.
Since $H(s)$ has no zeros or poles in the closed right half plane,
$\log(H(s))$ has no poles there. The function $\frac{\log(H(s))}{s}$ is thus
analytic in the region enclosed by the contour $\Gamma$ in the figure below (that excludes the origin). The motivation for this integrand is to get something like the integrand suggested by Kwin van der Keen.

By the Cauchy-Goursat theorem the contour integral,
$$\oint\limits_\Gamma \frac{\log(H(s))}{s} \mathrm{d}\Gamma = 0$$
Now breaking up the contour into segments 1-4 as in the figure,
$$
\underbrace{
            \int_R^r \frac{\log(H(i\omega))}{i\omega}\mathrm{d}(i\omega)
         }_\text{segment 1}
       + \underbrace{
            \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0
                \frac{\log(H(r e^{i\phi}))}{r e^{i\phi}}\mathrm{d}(r e^{i\phi})
         }_\text{segment 2}
       + \underbrace{\int_r^R \frac{\log(H(x))}{x}\mathrm{d}x}_\text{segment 3}
       + \underbrace{
            \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 
                \frac{\log(H(R e^{i\phi}))}{R e^{i\phi}}\mathrm{d}(R e^{i\phi})
         }_\text{segment 4}
       = 0
$$
Simplifying these integrals,
$$
         \int_R^r \frac{\log(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega
       + i \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 \log(H(r e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
       + \int_r^R \frac{\log(H(x))}{x}\mathrm{d}x
       + i \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(H(R e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
       = 0
$$
The first integral can be separated into the
magnitude and phase components of $H(i\omega)$, leading to
$$
        \int_R^r \frac{\log(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega
      = \int_R^r \frac{\log|H(i\omega)|}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
      + i \int_R^r \frac{\arg(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
$$
Making this substitution and collecting the real and imaginary parts,
$$
        \begin{gathered}
            \left[
                \int_R^r \frac{\log|H(i\omega)|}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
              + \int_r^R \frac{\log(H(x))}{x}\mathrm{d}x
            \right] \\
         + i\left[
                \int_R^r \frac{\arg(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
              + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 \log(H(r e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
              + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(H(R e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
            \right] = 0
        \end{gathered}
$$
The imaginary part must be separately equal to zero. Thus,
$$
        \int_R^r \frac{\arg(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
      + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 \log(H(r e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
      + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(H(R e^{i\phi}))\mathrm{d}\phi
      = 0
$$
Taking the limit of this equation as $R \to \infty$ and $r \to 0$, while noting that

$\lim_{s\to 0} H(s) = \frac{b_0}{a_0}$,
so $\lim_{r\to 0} \log(H(r e^{i\phi})) = \log\left(\frac{b_0}{a_0}\right)$,
$\lim_{s\to\infty} H(s) = 1$,
so $\lim_{R\to\infty} \log(H(R e^{i\phi})) = 0$ and
the contour integral being zero is still valid in the limit,

we obtain
$$
        \int_\infty^0 \frac{\arg(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
      - \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{b_0}{a_0}\right)
      + 0
      = 0
$$
Thus,
$$
        \int_0^\infty \frac{\arg(H(i\omega))}{\omega}\mathrm{d}\omega  
      = -\frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{b_0}{a_0}\right)
$$
If $b_0 > a_0$, then the right hand side is negative.
So the integrand must be negative over some region.
Thus there exists $\omega > 0$ such that $\arg(H(i\omega)) < 0$.

Phase is an angle to which one can add any interger amount times a full rotation (i.e. 360 when using degrees or $2\pi$ when using radians) and still represent the same thing. So in order to obtain a unique value forvthe phase at each frequency I will make the following assumptions. For minimum-phase transfer functions there are no poles or zeros on the imaginary axis, so no jumps in phase of $\pm180^\circ$, therefore I will assume that the phase is continuous as a function of frequency. Furthermore, with bi-proper monic numerator and denominator polynomials and $a_0,b_0>0$ at low and high frequencies the asymptote of the slope of the magnitude is zero and the complex value of the transfer function is positive real, so I will also assume that the starting phase is zero.
Using the same assumptions as the unique construction of phase it is possible to relate it to the magnitude according to [1]
\begin{align}
m(\omega) &= -\frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(\tau)}{\tau - \omega} d\tau, \tag{1} \\
\phi(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{m(\tau)}{\tau - \omega} d\tau, \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $P$ denotes the Cauchy principal value and it is assumed that both $m(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$ go to $0$ as $|\omega|\to\infty$, where $m(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega)$ are the magnitude and phase respectively as defined below
\begin{align}
H(j\omega) &= |H(j\omega)|\,e^{j\,\text{arg}(H(j\omega))}, \tag{3} \\
\log(H(j\omega)) &= \underbrace{\log(|H(j\omega)|)}_{m(\omega)} + j\,\underbrace{\text{arg}(H(j\omega))}_{\phi(\omega)}. \tag{4}
\end{align}
Furthermore, it is also required that $\log(H(j\omega))$ is analytic for $\omega\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,\text{Im}(z)\geq0\}$, which comes down to that $H(s)$ does not have poles and zeros in closed right half plane.
The limit assumption requires that $\log(H(j\omega))\to0$ and thus $H(j\omega)\to1$ as $|\omega|\to\infty$. For the considered systems in the question this is the case, since the numerator and the denominator are of the same order and monic.
In general one has $H(j\omega)\to r$ as $|\omega|\to\infty$. One could use $H(j\omega)+1-r$ instead of $H(j\omega)$ in $(3)$ and $(4)$ to ensure the limit assumption; one does have to check if the new transfer function doesn't have zeros in closed right half plane. If $r\neq0$ then one could instead also scale it by using $r^{-1} H(j\omega)$ instead of $H(j\omega)$ in $(3)$ and $(4)$. Using this scaling it can be shown that $(1)$ and $(2)$, using $(3)$ and $(4)$, are equivalent to
\begin{align}
\log(|H(j\omega)|) &= -\frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{arg}(H(j\tau)) - \text{arg}(H(j\infty))}{\tau - \omega} d\tau + \log(|H(j\infty)|), \tag{5} \\
\text{arg}(H(j\omega)) &= \frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\log(|H(j\tau)|) - \log(|H(j\infty)|)}{\tau - \omega} d\tau + \text{arg}(H(j\infty)). \tag{6}
\end{align}
Evaluating $(5)$ at $\omega=0$ and using that $\tau$ and $\text{arg}(H(j\tau))$ are odd functions reduces it to
$$
\log(|H(j0)|) = -\frac{2}{\pi} P \int_0^\infty \frac{\text{arg}(H(j\tau))}{\tau} d\tau + \log(|H(j\infty)|). \tag{7}
$$
Since $\text{arg}(H(j0))=0$ and assuming that the limit $\text{arg}(H(j\tau))/\tau$ as $\tau\to0$ exists, therefore $P$ can be omitted, so $(7)$ is equivalent to
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{arg}(H(j\tau))}{\tau} d\tau = \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{|H(j\infty)|}{|H(j0)|}\right). \tag{8}
$$
The result from $(8)$ has also been found earlier [2].
In your case $|H(j0)|=b_0/a_0>1$ and $|H(j\infty)|=1$, so the integral from $(8)$ has to be negative. The integral itself is a weighted sum of the phase, with the weight always non-negative. So the only way for the integral to evaluate to something negative is when the phase itself is negative atleast for some frequencies.
[1] Bechhoefer, J. (2011). Kramers–Kronig, Bode, and the meaning of zero. American Journal of Physics, 79(10), 1053-1059.
[2] Bode, H. W. (1940). Relations between attenuation and phase in feedback amplifier design. The Bell System Technical Journal, 19(3), 421-454.
